# Rails - sanitize complete application parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, sanitization

To improve the security of a site, is this a correct way to check and sanitize each param in the complete application?

Like, By adding a method in **ApplicationController before_filter:** to sanitize all the parameters. please guide & explain.

I'm using Rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9

Comment: what are you trying to sanitize against by adding a before filter? as per understanding rails itself provide a lot security against attacks. Please have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: Trying to sanitize all the Params. on every request, all params will be sanitized. I'm just discussing, whether its a correct way to do it in this way

Comment: or do we really need to do this to improve security and also clean the input from all the bad characters or injections